# How do I make a rythm-like bot play music when it joins a voice channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, youtube-dl

Is it possible to make a music discord bot play a specific song (from a youtube link) until it has something else to play?

For context, I would like this bot to play "standby" which at the moment is the youtube link to the LBP pod music.
Bots like Rythm would join a channel and wait for someone to give it a command to play a specific song. I would like this bot to join a channel and play a song until it is given another song to play.

For example:
if the prefix is "."

Rythm:

.join --> Rythm joins a voice channel.

.play *https://youtube.com/watch?v=BLAHBLAHBLAH* --> Rythm plays v=BLAHBLAHBLAH

What I want to achieve with my bot:

.join --> Bot joins voice channel and plays standby

standby = https://youtube.com/watch?v=SPECIFICLINK

.play https://youtube.com/watch?v=BLAHBLAHBLAH --> Bot stops playing standby and starts playing v=BLAHBLAHBLAH

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import random
from quotes import *
import time

standby = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5T4wrSDaQvY"

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(random.choice(notinvc))
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    @commands.command()
    async def leave(self,ctx):
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()




    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            await voice_channel.connect() 
        if ctx.voice_client is not ctx.author.voice:
            voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            time.sleep(1)
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
            await ctx.send("joining alternate vc")
            await ctx.send("i've bumped into an issue. please try again.")
            
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)
```